# Get href those who have title using jsoup parsing

Tags: android, css, parsing, jsoup

When I parsed the URL I got several `href`but I want the `href`which has title.Kindly let me get the answer

```
<a href="detailnews.asp?newsid=18318" title="Power shutdown areas in Chennai on 13-04-15">
<a href="detailnews.asp?newsid=18318">
```

My jsoup CSS query be like this to get the href

```
#table13>tbody>tr>td>a
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change your CSS selector like this: `#table13>tbody>tr>td>a[title]`. The "title" in brackets will get you only `a` which have a "title" attribute. Some code:

```
Document myDocument = Jsoup.connect("http://example.com/").get();

//selects "a" with a "title" attribute
Elements elements = myDocument.select("#table13>tbody>tr>td>a[title]");

for (Element e : elements) {
   System.out.println(e.attr("title")); //print contents of "title" attribute

   System.out.println(e.attr("href")); //print contents of "href" attribute
}
```